# Git server host authorized_keys file not identifying users id_rsa.pub key asking server password

Tags: ssh

Our git server authorized_keys file is not identifying anyone's id_rsa.pub key from this morning before it worked fine, from past 6 months never faced this issue. All repo's having same problem even on new repo's too.

### things i did:

1) checked on git host server .ssh/authorized_key file and permissions looks good (having 600 permissions).
2) Took backup of .ssh folder, regenerated new and created new authorized_key file also added new id_rsa.pub key even same problem.

kindly help me on this, all users are not able to pull/push/clone even me too.

### Only problem i found i dont know it is a problem or not also

when i executed `ls -lart authorized_keys *` command on git server 
it shows two authorized_keys files

### output:

```
[git@xxxxx .ssh]$ ls -lart authorized_keys *

-rw------- 1 git git 404 Oct 22 17:59 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 git git 404 Oct 22 17:59 authorized_keys
```

Regards,
sankarbheema

Comment: you are seeing the autohtorized_keys two times, because "*" is expanded to all files in the directory (including `authorized_keys`), so you are basically running `ls -l authorized_keys authorized_keys`

Comment: Please check the permissions of `~git/` and `~git/.ssh/` as well, and [add them to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13013192/edit).  (I.e. I'm asking for the output of `ls -ld ~git ~git/.ssh`)

Comment: Check if you can SSH in without a password, if not it's not a git problem. But it will be easier to debug as you can see what error message you get.

Comment: @ghoti o/p of [ls -ld ~git ~git/.ssh] is
[git@xxxx home]$ ls -ld ~git ~git/.ssh

**drwxrwxr-x 28 git git 4096 Oct 22 18:22 /home/git
drwx------  2 git git 4096 Oct 23 09:39 /home/git/.ssh**

Comment: @PetervanderDoes it is asking git host server password, i am unable to SSH, even after adding new SSH public key, when i had given git server host password it is able to clone, pull, push, can you suggest me where i have to look error msgs.

Comment: @PetervanderDoes i got below error on file gitweb.error.log  
**[Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] [error] [client 192.xx.xx.69] [Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] gitweb.cgi: Scalar found where operator expected at /etc/gitweb.conf line 2, near "$projects_list"  
[Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] [error] [client 192.xx.xx.69] [Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] gitweb.cgi: \t(Missing semicolon on previous line?)  
[Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] [error] [client 192.xx.xx.69] [Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] gitweb.cgi: Scalar found where operator expected at /etc/gitweb.conf line 4, near "$site_name"**

Comment: **[Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] [error] [client 192.xx.xx.69] [Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] gitweb.cgi: \t(Missing semicolon on previous line?)
[Mon Oct 22 14:13:18 2012] [error] [client 192.xx.xx.69] Can't call method "http" on an undefined value at /var/www/git/gitweb.cgi line 3401.
[Mon Oct 22 14:14:01 2012] [error] [client 192.xx.xx.69] sh: /root/bin/git: Permission denied**

Comment: @user1758788 - pasting stuff like this into comments makes it almost completely unreadable.  Since this is important information about your question, it's a better idea to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13013192/edit) and add it there. That said, see my answer...

Answer (score 5):

You said in comments:

```
[git@xxxx home]$ ls -ld ~git ~git/.ssh
drwxrwxr-x 28 git git 4096 Oct 22 18:22 /home/git
drwx------  2 git git 4096 Oct 23 09:39 /home/git/.ssh
```

While this is acceptable permissions for git's .ssh directory, SSH is refusing to accept connections because git's home directory is group writable.  SSH realizes that group writability means that other users might be able to effect changes on ~/.ssh, so it refuses to trust the files in there.

The location of the log that tells you about this depends on your operating system.  On my system (FreeBSD), the file to look at is `/var/log/auth.log`, which contains a line like:

```
Oct 23 06:45:25 pc sshd[29724]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /usr/home/ghoti
```

To fix this, change remove the group write bit.

```
sudo chmod 755 ~git
```

Oh, and the reason that `ls -lart authorized_keys *` shows two authorized_keys files is that you are specifying that file twice - once explicitly, and once as member of the wildcard (`*`).

Comment: Thanks for All posts, It was resolved, the issue was IT guy changed server subnet mask address and it made problems, it worked once reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for All posts, It was resolved, the issue was IT guy changed server subnet mask address and it made problems, it worked once reverted